# How to close Javascript alertbox by using the enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to close Javascript alertbox by using the enter key..

```
function validate(){
     if (document.getElementById("<%=username.ClientID%>").value == "") {
         alert("Please select UserID.");              
         return false;
     }
}
```

Actually I'm using custom Alert like:
Var msg=new alert();
This is not closing...

Comment: what is the problem with this code ?, is it not working or some else

Comment: Question is not clear ... Please provide more details

Comment: enter key **DOES** close the alert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to control an `alert()` other than initially creating it. There are no events and no way of changing it once it is created. If you need more control, consider creating a modal dialog, for example with jQuery UI.

[Docs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: Maybe in the not so far future, we may be able to have a bit more of control over these `DOM0` APIs when Shadow DOM is standardized.